# Stack of generic list gets cleared when pushed list is cleared

Tags: c#, parameter-passing, generic-collections

I have a little problem when i want to do some operations in c#. I will give you a little example.

```
Stack<List<HufmannLetter>> steps = new Stack<List<HufmannLetter>>();
List<HufmannLetter> letterList = new List<HufmannLetter>();    

while(true){

    letterList.Add("asd");
    letterList.Add("sad");

    steps.Push(letterList);
    letterlist.Clear();    
}
```

In this code, I want to push my linkedlist to a stack than remove all the items in the list. When I clear the list, my stack's first index disappears because it passed by reference. Am i wrong? Because I dont know why it happens.

So I use pass by value method.

```
Stack<List<HufmannLetter>> steps = new Stack<List<HufmannLetter>>();
List<HufmannLetter> letterList = new List<HufmannLetter>();

while(true) {

    letterList.Add("asd");
    letterList.Add("sad");

    List<HufmannLetter> tempLetterList = new List<HufmannLetter>(letterList);
    steps.Push(tempLetterList);
    letterlist.Clear();    
}
```

Is it a good way to solve a problem? This way it is working, but readability decreases. What do you suggest me?

Thanks...

Comment: "Am i wrong?" Yes, there's no pass-by-reference in the code you've shown. You can tell that by the lack of `ref` and `out`. I suggest you read http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html and http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/references.html Note that passing a reference by value is not the same as pass-by-reference.

Answer (score 3):

Just create a new `List<HufmannLetter>` object inside the loop and add that to the stack. Reusing the same list object won't have any performance benefits.

```
Stack<List<HufmannLetter>> steps = new Stack<List<HufmannLetter>>();

while(true)
{
    List<HufmannLetter> letterList = new List<HufmannLetter>();

    letterList.Add("asd");
    letterList.Add("sad");

    steps.push(letterList);
}
```

Comment: Yeah i know, it doesnt effect my performance but im considering about my code's understandability. But if there arent any way, i wont change my code. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: None of the answers explain OP's `When i clear the list, my stack's first index disappears because it passed by reference. Am i wrong? Because i dont know why it happens.`!

Comment: @Berkin, what do you mean by _"there aren't any way"_? My example is not identical to yours.

Answer (score 1):

You can create `new List<HufmannLetter>()` and give in the constructor the previous list, this will create new object which will be not cleared.

```
while(condition)
{
    letterList.Add("asd");
    letterList.Add("sad");

    steps.push(new List<HufmannLetter>(letterList));
    letterlist.Clear();
}
```

**EDIT**

So `List<T>` is reference type, you are putting the `letterList` in the stack. In this way you are transferring the value of the reference `List<T>` in the stack *item*. So your letterList variable reference the same object as the item in your stack. When you clear the items from letterList, they are cleared in the item of the stack too.

Check what is [**Reference Types**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx)

Comment: None of the answers explain OP's `When i clear the list, my stack's first index disappears because it passed by reference. Am i wrong? Because i dont know why it happens.`!

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful I think the op understands why the values are cleared from his lists in the stack. If he doesn't understand it I will write a little explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`List<>` is a mutable reference type.

When you pass a `List<>` to a method, you pass a copy of *the reference*. So you just tell which `List<>` it is. That will not copy (clone) the entire contents of the `List<>`.

When you put (`Push`) a `List<>` on the `Stack<>`, what the `Stack<>` really keeps is a copy of a reference to this instance of `List<>`. If that instance is later modified, for example with `.Add("asd")` or with `.Clear()`, this "mutation" will be seen whether you follow the reference kept by the `Stack<>` or another reference you have, from the local variable. *Both references "point" to the same instance of `List<>`.*

When, in your code, you say:

```
letterList.Clear(); // do not change reference, follow reference and mutate the instance it refers to
```

that will modify (mutate) the existing instance of `List<>` so it becomes empty. This change will be seen by anyone holding a reference to this particular instance of `List<>`.

If instead you had done:

```
letterList = new List<string>(); // create new instance, change reference to point there (reference assignment), old instance is unchanged
```

that would have "moved" the reference of `letterList` to point to a *new* instance of `List<>`. This would not affect people with other references to the "old" instance.

---

The title *Pass By Reference Usage* is misleading. It should have been Reference Types And Passing References or something like that.

Answer (score -1):

you can also do that as

```
Stack<List<HufmannLetter>> steps = new Stack<List<HufmannLetter>>();

while(true)
{
var tempList = new List<HufmannLetter>;
tempList.add("asd");
steps.push(tempList);
 }
```

or you can try this

```
steps.push(tempList.ToList());
   tempList.Clear();
```

Comment: This is the same answer as botond.botos which was given before 6 min.

Comment: Yes it is but please check the second part